# windows CMD batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I was wondering about the behavior of the `for /f` command specifically.
I am doing an `ipconfig /all` to a file; pulling the lines that have IPv4 Address to another file. Then I would like to read this file and isolate the IPv4 address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Then I would like to reread this file and select an IP address based on the first 2 octets
Then I would like to use the selected ip to build a line with the IP appended to it.
It seems to me that the `for /f` command behaves in a manner that I do not understand.

```
: ADDResses.cmd 5/8
::
:: turn on echo
:: clear screen
:: ipconfig into a find looking of the string IP address.  and send to a file
:: cat out the file to check
::
::
:: output of the file is listed below
::
::C:\Scripts>type c:\scripts\address.txt
::
::   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XX.XX.XX.XX
::   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XX.XX.XX.XX
::C:\Users\william.reagan\Scripts>
::
::echo Usage: print_head COUNT FILENAME

echo on

del ipAddrLine.txt

cls

:: following line takes output of ipconfig and sends lines with ip address to the address.txt file

echo "::select IP address  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
ipconfig | findstr /r "IPv4 Address.*[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*"  > %~dp0address.txt


call :print_head 10 %~dp0address.txt
goto :after
::::::::::::::::
::
:: print_head
:: skip first blank line
:: send the line to ipAddrLine.txt
:: Prints the first non-blank (10) %1 lines in the file %2.
::
::
:print_head
echo "::starting print head ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a counter=0

for /f ^"usebackq^ eol^=^

^ delims^=^" %%a in (%2) do (
        if "!counter!"=="%%a" goto :after
        echo %%a >> %~dp0ipAddrLine.txt
        set /a counter+=1
)

:after
::
::

echo "::checking just the ip address:::type ipaddrline file to make sure it closes:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::"
::fouteenth token is ip address which occurs after the 13th space
::
type %~dp0ipAddrLine.txt
FOR /F "tokens=14* delims= " %%f in (%~dp0ipAddrLine.txt) DO (
                set @IPaddr=%%f
                echo %@IPaddr%
                ::
                echo.%@IPaddr% | findstr /C:"10.32" 1>nul

                if errorlevel 1 (
                echo. pattern not found
                ) ELSE (
                echo %@IPaddr%
                goto createAgentLines
                )
  )

goto :doNotinstall
:createAgentLines            

::create lines for the agent.properties file

set multiNICline1=tw.rpc.interfaceAddr=
set multiNICline2=java.rmi.server.hostname=
set completeLine1=%multiNICline1%%@IPaddr
```

Answer (score 1):

Type `HELP FOR` in the CMD window.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a for loop that will give you the IP address by itself from ipconfig /all:

```
for /f "tokens=13 delims=(: " %%p in ('ipconfig /all ^| findstr "IPv4"') do echo %%p
```

Here is a for loop that will give you the IP address in blocks so you get for the first two octets, the IP address, and an IP ADDR using the two octets:

```
for /f "tokens=3-6 delims=(:. " %%P in ('ipconfig /all ^| findstr "IPv4"') do (
    echo IP ADDRESS: %%P.%%Q.%%R.%%S
    echo Two Octets: %%P.%%Q
    echo New IPADDR: %%P.%%Q.0.1
)
```

For more information on for loops, in the command window, type in:

```
for /?
```

EDIT:

`for /f` - The Parsing Loop

`"tokens=3-6"` - Means to use ONLY the 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th occurrence of the pattern

`"delims=(: "` - Means we're using `(` `:` and  to split by (this is the pattern)

`%%P` - is the starting variable that we're using.  They're case sensitive and alphabetic.  It doesn't really matter which range you use for a single loop like this, ie, we could have used "%%A"

`in` - Means: from the output of the following command line

`('ipconfig /all ^| findstr "IPv4"')` - this is the command line that we're running; since we're only interested in the IPv4 values, we're isolated them using `findstr`

`do (` - for the output (per line), do the following

`echo IP ADDRESS: %%P.%%Q.%%R.%%S` - print to screen the 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th occurance to the screen.

`echo Two Octets: %%P.%%Q` - print to screen the 3rd and 4th occurance to the screen.

`echo New IPADDR: %%P.%%Q.0.1` - print to screen the 3rd and 4th occurance to the screen with additional values

`)` - Telling the `do (` to end, stopping the execution.

Check out http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm for really nice documentation

Comment: the code works; when you have really slow day an explaination would be really helpful in the mean time i will try and decipher how it is working thanks again.........

Comment: Here is a link that explains (fairly well) about how for loops work and the caveats around them: http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm